# quoted javascript and JSON to PHP

Tags: php, json

this javascript:

```
"jform[username]": {
                required: true,
                minlength:5,
                maxlength:15,
                remote: "modules/mod_easiness_register/libs/elements/db_checker.php"
            },
```

has to pass it's value to this PHP script:

```
    if (isset($_REQUEST['jform[username]'])) {         
    $username = $_REQUEST['jform[username]'];                                                   
    $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);                                  
    $check_for_username = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM $users WHERE username='$username'"); 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check_for_username)) {
        echo "false";                                                                           
    } else {
        echo "true";                                                                           
    }
}
```

the ""(quotes) around  **"jform[username]"** are the trouble makers, but I have to use those quotes to make the brackets[] work (and I need those brackets as well). I think JSON can't handle this. Do you know a way around this? I hope you understand the problem. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Technically, double quotes are REQUIRED around every key in a JSON object - and some JSON parsers would throw an error for your object due to the lack of double quotes on all your other keys. So the double quotes aren't causing a problem, they're preventing one. St.Woland is correct below - PHP will automatically turn that into an array for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your PHP script you should check for `$_REQUEST['jform']['username']`, and this will solve your problem.

Comment: thank you so much, learning so much on this website! :) I will accept your answer as soon as I can